# What's wrong with the rotation of my lists?

Tags: java, arrays, list, rotation

In that part of the code I only want to rotate one of the list, but both had been rotated.

```
for(int i = 0; i< 1000000000; i++) { 
    Collections.rotate(newList, positions);
    System.out.println("New list: "+newList);
    System.out.println("Normal list: "+list);
    if(dosListasIguales(list, newList)) {
        movimientos = i;
        break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you create `newList`? If you did something like `List newList = list` then they are the same `List`.

Comment: We cannot tell from what you have presented, though it seems that the two lists in question must be aliased somehow.  Present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem if you want a confident answer.

Comment: nothing can be said about  about `list` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have copied reference of `list` to `newList` somewhere. So any changes in the `newList` affects `list`.

Use this for copying:

```
List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);
```

instead of:

```
List<Integer> newList = list;
```

Comment: @CarlosCastañodelCastillo `List<Integer> newList = list;` is the reference copying point. You should use`List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list);`